# List of all features inside a buffer (Web map)

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers-2, geoext, ext-js

I have web map, created in the combination of: ExtJS 5, Openlayers 2, Geoext 2, and Geoserver.

My layers are in postgis linked to geoserver.

My scenario are 1 base map, an 10 normal layers. Actually i have a tree panel and i can view correct all the layers in the viewport.

The idea is the user click a point in the map and in someplace also input the meters to make a buffer of that point. Next i need to get a list of all the features of my 10 layers that are inside that buffer (ring).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to this is to use a [WFS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs) call from OpenLayers to GeoServer. The full answer will probably require some experimentation to see what works best for your situation.

1. Use OpenLayers to construct a Xm buffer around the point clicked and ask GeoServer for all features in each layer that are [`within`](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/filters.html#spatial-operators) or [`intersect`](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/filters.html#spatial-operators) that polygon.
2. Ask GeoServer for all features in each layer that are within Xm of the point ([`DWithin`](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/filters.html#spatial-operators)), this requires that your data is in a projection measured in metres.
3. Construct a [WPS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wps) request to manage the buffering, reprojection and collecting of layers into a single answer.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I agree, i think is the best method, i'm doing some test in Openlayers to draw the buffer around the point clicked, in the next days im going to share my code, and i appreciate if you help me again, to complete all the steps. Regards...